# Extracting Country name (or initials) from Magento

Tags: php, magento, country

I'm trying to get the country name "United States" (or initials "USA"/"US"). I've tried a bunch of variations on the following:

```
echo Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer()->getCountry();
$countryName = Mage::getModel('directory/country')->load(Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer()->getCountry())->getName();
error_log("countryName = $countryName");
```

The first call "seems" to work, as I get a 6 back (USA). But after that I'm not able to find out how to map that to a proper name or slug.

I've seen posts where the programmers gets a list of all the country names and id's but I don't want to iterate through all the combinations to find the name.

TIA!

EDIT:
Per clockworkgeeks' suggestion, I've tried:

```
$customer = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer();
error_log(print_r($customer, true));
$countryCode = $customer->getDefaultBillingAddress()->getCountry();
```

However, the 3rd line fails w/the call to getCountry(). Perhaps getDefaultBillingAddress() is not returning on object. Error message:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function getCountry() on a non-object in ...
```

Thoughts? The $customer object is coming back correctly, though the **CLASS** is a MYCLIENT_Customer_Model_Customer Object ... perhaps it doens't extend the proper parent to give it access to getCountry?

Edit: (Solution):  Added as an answer.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So, I solved this by doing:

```
customer_model_object = Mage::getSingleton('customer/customer');
$session = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session');
$country_name = $customer_model_object->load($session->getId())->getResource()->getAttribute('country')->getFrontend()->getValue($customer_model_object);
```

Thanks for the help. You were right clockworkgeek, this is an attribute added to the customer entity from the adminhtml. I had to go through all this jazz to get access to the country slug, example: "united states".

Answer (score 14):

Normally information like the country is not stored in the customer entity at all, I'm unsure why you get a "6".

```
$customer = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer();
$countryCode = $customer->getDefaultBillingAddress()->getCountry();
// $countryCode looks like "US"
$country = Mage::getModel('directory/country')->loadByCode($countryCode);
echo $country->getName(); // looks like "United States"
```

Comment: Maybe this is because of the EAV system and perhaps something we've built or extended. Again, I've just literally been dropped into this project, my overall Magento knowledge is slim/nil.

Comment: That fails, the call to getCountry() doesn't work, so perhaps the getDefaultBillingAddress() is not returning an object. Implementation in my OP.

Comment: That suggests your site has been altered to not use a separate address object, or the customer you're inspecting simply does not have any address. When I look at `directory_country` table in the database it has no numeric field so cannot see how you are supposed to use a value of "6". Perhaps there is a local extension (check for a MYCLIENT folder) which is using that value in a way you can copy.

Comment: Right on, I'm going to dig into their model now. Thanks, I'll report back once I figure it out.

Comment: Solved, +1 to you for you help.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe this helps:

```
$countryName = 
    Mage::getModel('directory/country')->load($countryCode)->getName();
```

From: http://blog.chapagain.com.np/magento-get-country-and-region-collection/

Comment: How to get full country name instead of a country code, here is my code return only country code:  https://www.pastiebin.com/5ce2558df3370 @miku